# Maven is suddenly giving me "Failed to collect dependencies for" errors, what changed?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

For some reason I'm experiencing the following Maven error, this was working before so I've no idea what changed (except that Eclipse updated itself, but I don't know :

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project amplify: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project com.o:a:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:
>   Failed to collect dependencies for
>   [org.simpleframework:simple:jar:4.1.21 (compile),
>   org.testng:testng:jar:6.7 (test), org.jsoup:jsoup:jar:1.6.3 (compile),
>   com.restfb:restfb:jar:1.6.9 (compile), com.google.guava:guava:jar:13.0
>   (compile), com.google.code:morphia:jar:0.91 (compile),
>   org.imgscalr:imgscalr-lib:jar:4.2 (compile),
>   commons-io:commons-io:jar:20030203.000550 (compile),
>   org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.1 (compile),
>   net.java.dev.jets3t:jets3t:jar:0.8.1 (compile),
>   org.jooq:jooq:jar:2.4.0 (compile), org.jooq:jooq-meta:jar:2.4.0
>   (compile), mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.21 (compile),
>   com.jolbox:bonecp:jar:0.8.0-alpha1 (compile),
>   com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.2.2 (compile),
>   org.antlr:stringtemplate:jar:4.0.2 (compile),
>   org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.9.5-rc1 (compile), rome:rome:jar:1.0
>   (compile), rome:modules:jar:0.3.2 (compile), args4j:args4j:jar:2.0.16
>   (compile), ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.0.6 (compile),
>   ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.0.6 (compile),
>   joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.1 (compile), rhino:js:jar:1.7R2 (compile),
>   org.apache.commons:commons-math3:jar:3.0 (compile),
>   javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.5 (compile), quickdt:quickdt:jar:0.0.1
>   (compile), com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:jar:1.3.11 (compile)]: No
>   versions available for
>   org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:[1.8,1.9) within specified
>   range -> [Help 1]

I'm using Maven version 3.0.3.  does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There **was** corrupt metadata for the jackson-mapper-asl dependency for aws and spring.  It has since been resolved.  I would perform a clean and see if that fixes the issue.  See [the bug here](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JACKSON-871)

This is also related to [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12651959/maven-build-error-no-versions-available-for-org-codehaus-jacksonjackson-core-as)

Comment: I tried a "mvn clean" but I'm still getting this error when I do a "mvn assembly:assembly" :-(

Answer (score 1):

Check what external repository your pom.xml is configured to connect to... I've seen it before when a well known lib in an external maven repository was accidentally removed resulting in the similar error (not able to collect dependency). To make sure its not the case, just go to that public repo and check if your artifact version is available.

The best way, is to have your own (company/department wide) maven repository where you should have all the versions of artifacts deployed. This way you are in full control of what is available/unavailable in the repository.